# Redirect dynamically from internal pages

Tags: php

I have multiple buttons in a webpage, such as - Home, Feedback, Contact us, Logout.
 
The login page will differentiate the user based on his department like CS, EE, ME and displays the Home page. 
 The home page is different for different departments.

Here, Feedback.php and Contact_us.php are common for all streams. 
Now, my concern is, when CS student logs in, how to redirect him to CS Home page, using "Home" button in Feedback.php and contact_us.php

I can get his department from the username.

Thanks.

Comment: Use the same method you use to differentiate which home page the user should go to after logging in to determine what the link of the home button is.

Comment: at the time of feedback.php and contact_us.php. you need to check your user type and set the home link based on that user type. you can set the conditional dynamic link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a switch statement based off of the department to output a different href attribute in the anchor tag wrapped around "Home".

```
switch($department) {
    case 'CS':
        $homeHref = 'cs_home.php';
        break;
    //and so on
}
```

The anchor tag would look like this after generating that link.

```
<a href="<? echo $homeHref; ?>">Home</a>
```